# What does "share the passion" mean?

Tags: prepositions

For example, what would it be defined if used in this sentence:

> We *share the passion* in reading fantasy adventure book series.

Also, should *in* be replaced with *of*?

Comment: It means exactly what the words say: you both have the same passion, i.e. enthusiasm about reading fantasy books. I thinka better preposition would be _for_.

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't you just put it as an answer? :D

Comment: It seems too trivial

Comment: @Barmar With *for*, I think I'd use *a* rather than *the*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid form.  Basically means "we enjoy this and think you will too".  Either "in" or "of" will work, though "of" is probably preferred.